# What creates the symlinks in the bin folder in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm having some issues since I've changed the vendor folder path for a symfony2 project. (Its currently outside of the project)

But right now the symlinks (phpunit, doctrine, etc) inside the bin folder are wrong.

When composer runs in which part or what actually creates the symlinks that appear in the bin folder (like phpunit) that point to lib in the vendor folder? Where those paths are comming from?

Thanks

Comment: How have you changed the vendor path? In config or with a symlink? I don't think that's supported use case by the way. Why are you doing this? Here's where binaries are linked: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/5fbd4ee0c9d23d51175c4d1491482074e0fe56f2/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php#L193

Comment: @JakubZalas yes its supported, actually fully supported you can have you vendor folder anywhere you want. Whats why you have local and global  configurations that allows to specify the vendor-dir. ```composer config -g -l```

Comment: Actually is composer that generates all those symlinks. Based on what? I dont know, probably some configuration in each library that composer downloads.

Comment: see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the vendor directory and run `./composer.php install` and you'll get the symlinks back. I couldn't find a way to force recreation of the bins

Comment: If I ever have problems like that, I just delete the vendor/ directory - and bin/ (if it has been moved out of vendors by a setting in composer.json). It will have to download it all again (but much it it could be cached by Composer).